# How to set 'spring.datasource.url' inside a Docker Container

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I created a Spring Boot application which uses a MySQL database. I use a docker-compose to launch the database.

```
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'example' # TODO: Change this      
    volumes:
      - "./config/my.conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf"
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

The Spring Boot Application (Backend) currently does not use Docker, I run it inside Eclipse. Before launching the Backend I have to grep the Docker Container for IPAddress:

```
docker inspect mysql_ex_db_1 | grep 'IPAddress'
```

which results something like this (this exact address changes time-to time)

```
                "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",
```

Then I take this value and I set `spring.datasource.url` inside Eclipse in the file `Application.properties` with it.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.21.0.2:3306/employee_management_system?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

After this I can launch the Backend in Eclipse the Connection to database is there, everything works.

Now I want to move the launching of Backend from Eclipse to the same docker-compose file I use to launch the database. Therefore I built an image, and appended the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'example' # TODO: Change this      
    volumes:
      - "./config/my.conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf"
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
```

In this case how can I configure the IPAddress in `spring.datasource.url`?
The exact IPAddress changes whenever I re-launch the mysql containers.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.21.0.2:3306/employee_management_system?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

So what should I write instead of '172.21.0.2' ?

I tried **localhost** here but it
does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can set environment variables like `spring.datasource.url` outside of your docker image. This allows you to dynamically set these variables according to your deployment needs (like connecting to a dev or prod database).

All docker containers running from your docker-compose file run in the same virtual network and their service names correspond to their hostnames within this network. When you want to access your database from your dockerized spring backend the hostname and port will be `db:3306`. You can overwrite `spring.datasource.url` in your docker-compose file by introducing an environment variable like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'example' # TODO: Change this      
    volumes:
      - "./config/my.conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf"
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_management_system?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this env variable to your `backend` in `docker-compose`:

```
backend:
  ...
  environment:
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_management_system?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Spring Boot app, your spring.datasource.url must be like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:5432/my_db
```

(here I am connecting to a postgres db). Then you set the variable in your docker compose:

```
...
environment:
  DATABASE_HOST:container_name
```

you can also test outside a docker-compose, by command line like this:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m" --network=my_network -e DATABASE_HOST=postgres_container_name --name myapp myregistry/myimage:version
```